# Falha na Conexão FTP em C#

Tags: c#, ftp

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação *Console* em [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) que realiza a conexão com um servidor FTP (ou pelo menos deveria), tenho o seguinte código:

**Classe FTPConnection**

```
class FTPConnection
{
    private Connection con;
    private FtpWebRequest ftp;

    public FTPConnection(Connection c)
    {
        con = c;
    }

    public bool TestConnection(){
        string host = "ftp://" + con.Host;
        if (con.Port != null) host += ":" + con.Port;
        ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create( host );
        ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(con.User, con.Pass);
        try
        {
            WebResponse response = ftp.GetResponse();
            Util.Success("Conexão realizada com sucesso!");
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Util.Error("Falha na conexão: " + host);
            Util.Warning(e.Message);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Execução do Método**

```
Connection con = new Connection();
con.Host = "127.0.0.1";
con.User = "carlos";
con.Pass = "123123";
con.Port = "21";

FTPConnection FTPc = new FTPConnection(con);
if (!FTPc.TestConnection())
{
    Util.Warning("Não foi possível conectar com os dados informados...");
}
else
{
    Util.Success("Exito no teste de conexão.");
}
```

O retorno sempre é:

> Falha na conexão: ftp://127.0.0.1:21
>   O URI solicitado é inválido para o comando de FTP.
>   Não foi possível conectar com os dados informados...

Estou utilizando o FileZilla Server do XAMPP. O log de conexão dele quanto tento uma conexão é o seguinte:

> (000013)18/05/2015 17:28:07 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> Connected, sending welcome message...
>   (000013)18/05/2015 17:28:07 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.41 beta
>   (000013)18/05/2015 17:28:07 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)
>   (000013)18/05/2015 17:28:07 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
>   (000013)18/05/2015 17:28:07 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> disconnected.

Utilizando o FileZilla Client eu conecto normalmente com os mesmos dados de conexão:

```
Host: 127.0.0.1
User: carlos
Pass: 123123
Port: 21
```

Não sei se esse método `ftp.GetResponse();` é o correto para teste de conexão. Estou tentando utiliza-lo para testar a conexão. Se alguém souber o que está errado e puder adicionar um código de teste de conexão e um exemplo de conexão real (pois ainda não cheguei nessa parte) com envio de arquivos, na resposta eu agradeço.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolvi o problema da conexão adicionando o método do Request.

```
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
```